Generate Allure reports in GitHub Actions for 2 separate test runs
I have tests on RobotFramework, that run in GitHub Actions. Currently there is one workflow, that runs tests and generates Allure reports for them. And then report is deployed in GitHub Pages.
It looks like this:
jobs:

    Run_tests:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Run tests
          run: |
            robot --outputdir results --listener allure_robotframework:results/allure test_suite_folder
    Generate_report:
      needs: Run_tests
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      name: Generate Allure Report
      steps:
        - name: Get Allure history
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
          if: always()
          continue-on-error: true
          with:
            ref: gh-pages
            path: gh-pages
        
        - name: Generate Allure report with history
          uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@master
          if: always()
          id: allure-report
          with:
            allure_results: results/allure
            gh_pages: gh-pages
            allure_report: allure-report
            allure_history: allure-history
            keep_reports: 20
   
        - name: Deploy report to Github Pages
          if: always()
          uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v2
          env:
            PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
            PUBLISH_DIR: allure-history

Now I want to have other workflow with different test suite.
Ideally I'd like to have 2 different reports with different URLs. But I'm not sure if GitHub Pages allows this.
So I tried to store results for 2 suites in 2 different folders and then generate one single report from both of them
So Workflow_1 has
--listener allure_robotframework:results/allure/folder_1

and Workflow_2 has
--listener allure_robotframework:results/allure/folder_2

And each workflow should collect report from the parent folder
 - name: Generate Allure report with history
          uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@master
          if: always()
          id: allure-report
          with:
            allure_results: results/*
            gh_pages: gh-pages
            allure_report: allure-report
            allure_history: allure-history
            keep_reports: 20


But new report just overrides the old one.

You can achieve this by creating two different sub directorates inside your gh-pages branch. When collecting report lets say if your sub directory on the gh pages is backend_test then in allure report build you need to pass gh-pages : gh-pages/backend_test.
